# Can't load Google map in to web view

Tags: android, web, webview

I Can't open a specific Google map URL In To web view,

and this is my Code

```
WebView wv = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webPlace);
WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
ws.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
ws.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.sa/maps/place/Al+Com/@24.6930318,46.7746621,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x154b423825155cce");
```

but every time i try to run this code system force me to run this URL in to new activity of android web browser , but i need to open it in the same application activity pleas any one can help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//oncreate

```
  String url = "https://www.google.com.sa/maps/place/Al+Com/@24.6930318,46.7746621,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x154b423825155cce";


  new LoadSocialNetworkUrlTask().execute(url);
```

//asynctask

```
  public class LoadSocialNetworkUrlTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(SocialNetworkActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading,Please wait...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(final String... url) {
        try {

            ((WebView) webView).getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            ((WebView) webView).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            ((WebView) webView).setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                        SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO hide your progress image
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            ((WebView) webView).loadUrl(url[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            publishProgress(url);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           view.loadUrl(url);
           return true;
       }
```

}

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com.sa/maps/place/Al+Com/@24.6930318,46.7746621,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0000000000000000:0x154b423825155cce");
```